# Repeater.Items only populates in Button click event when I DataBind in that event, but all textbox inputs are empty

Tags: textbox, repeater, webforms

I have a repeater that is databound to a SqlDataSource

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Code") %>' ID="Code" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="NumberNeeded" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Needed") %>' /><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" Text="submit" OnClick="submit_Click" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="rtvFiltered" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to iterate over the repeater and get the value in NumberNeeded in submit_Click

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Repeater.DataBind(); //comment this guy and this.Repeater.Items has no items
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in this.Repeater.Items)
    {
        String code = ((HiddenField)item.FindControl("JournalCode")).Value;
        // below fails because "NumberNeeded" control doesn't have the Text input by the user.
        int numNeeded = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)item.FindControl("NumberNeeded")).Text);

        // Doing other stuff with numNeeded
    }
}
```

The repeater displays its items perfectly on the page, but when I click the submit button, this.Repeater.Items is empty (unless I call this.Repeater.DataBind() in that method).

I've tried explicitly data binding Repeater in Page_Load and Page_Init within and outside of a !Page.IsPostBack check, and everytime I either get no Items, or no Text value.

I have gotten an almost identical setup to work in the past, on a page without a master page. I've also noticed that this.Master.EnableViewState is false in the submit_Click method, no matter if I set it to true in Page_Init or Page_Load. this.EnableViewState is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the EnableViewState setting on the master page.

In the Page_Load method of the master page this.EnableViewState was getting set to false. I changed it to Page.EnableViewState and everything worked.

```
this.EnableViewState = Page.EnableViewState; // add to Master page Page_Load method
```

do'h

Answer (score 2):

As you state, you shouldn't need to call `DataBind()` in your code behind, so the problem may be with the data retrieval. Does your stored procedure take any parameters? Have you tried adding `CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"` to your SqlDataSource?

Comment: My stored procedure takes optional parameters, soI tried adding CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" in my SqlDataSource, and I got the same behavior (Repeater works fine on the page, but the Items property is still empty).